How do I get out of active object mode?
I don't think it's actually called active object mode, illustrator just kind of does the same thing and that's what it's called.  I was working on a single curve in my scene, then accidentally hit something, and now I can only see that curve.  The rest of my mesh objects still appear in the data outliner, they're just not visible.  Changing viewports doesn't help.  I'm assuming it's just some hot key I accidentally hit, but I don't want to try pressing a bunch of buttons to figure it out.

It's probably Local view. Hit the forward-slash key on the keyboard (bottom-right by the right Shift key). It should say 'Local' in the top-left corner of the 3D view.

As said by John Eason, this is called "Local view", and you can find it on the view menu also.


That was it, thank you!
